# Basic redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect the url of **`sample.mysite.com`** to

**`mysite.com/shops/index/sample.mysite.com`** . How can i do this using

**`.htaccess`** rules ?

**Note** : Here **sample** can be a variable ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /shops/index/sample.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,NE]
```

This will internally forward **sample.mysite.com** to **mysite.com/shops/index/sample.mysite.com** with the requested uri.

Comment: Will this change the URL on redirection ?

Comment: No this doesnt change the url.  If you want your browser url to change, you can use a R flag.

Comment: Ahyea i dont want

Comment: Sorry i am redirecting to **http://sample.mysite.com/shops/index/sample.mysite.com/index.php?/shops/index/sample.mysite.com/index.php** when am using this